# JavaFX 2 multispan cell table like MS Excel

Tags: java, javafx-2

I hope someone will be able to help to resolve my problem. 
I need the table like MS Excel with a fast scrolling. I use JavaFX 2 and can't find any example or solution. There are several examples on Swing, but I really need JavaFX 2. I've already tested TableView, GridPane but they work very slow with huge amount of data.

```
    package test

    import javafx.stage.Stage
    import javafx.scene.{Group, Scene}
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory
    import javafx.collections.{FXCollections}
    import javafx.application.Application
    import javafx.util.Callback
    import javafx.scene.control._
    import javafx.scene.layout.{GridPane}

   class TableTest extends Application {

  override def start(stage: Stage) = {

    val root = new Group
    val scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 700)
    val table = new TableView[Data]

    table.setPrefWidth(1000)
    table.setPrefHeight(700)

    val data = FXCollections.observableArrayList[Data]

    for(i <- 0 until 100) data.add(new Data)

    for(j <- 0 until 100) table.getColumns().add(createTextColumn(j.toString))

    table.setItems(data)

    root.getChildren().add(table)
    stage.setTitle("Table View Test JavaFX & Scala")
    stage.setWidth(1024)
    stage.setHeight(768)
    stage.setScene(scene)
    stage.show

  }

  def createTextColumn(index:String):TableColumn[Data, AnyRef] = {

    val activeCol = new TableColumn[Data, AnyRef](index)

    activeCol.setPrefWidth(128)

    activeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory[Data, AnyRef]("text"))

    val call = new Callback[TableColumn[Data, AnyRef], TableCell[Data, AnyRef]] {
      override def call(p1: TableColumn[Data, AnyRef]) : TableCell[Data, AnyRef] = {
        new TableCell[Data, AnyRef] {

          val grid = new GridPane
          val label = new Label
          grid.add(label, 0, 0)
          setGraphic(grid)

          override def updateItem(value: AnyRef, empty: Boolean) = {
            val row = getTableRow
            if (row != null && value != null) {
              label.setText(value.toString)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    activeCol.setCellFactory(call)

    return activeCol
  }

}


package test

import javafx.beans.property.{SimpleLongProperty, SimpleStringProperty}

class Data {
  val text = new SimpleStringProperty("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sit amet velit leo, in sodales lorem. Donec vel nisl tellus sed. ")
  def textProperty = text
  def getText : String = text.get
  def setText(value: String) = text.set(value)
}
```

I tested this code with Data class with only one string (128 bytes). But really it should be more than now. So, the question is: can I get something like MS Excel table with the same functionallity using JavaFX 2? 
P.S.: I also tested this code with pure Java but got the same result :(

Comment: TableView was too slow? Can you post your code? If JTable would work for you then you can mix swing with java fx2

Comment: JTable works fine but I need JavaFX 2.
Maybe you know how can I mix Swing and JavaFX 2?(it should be JavaFX application)

Comment: Some complex heavy component functionalities can be implemented by the 3rd party Javascript components and be loaded to Webview. For instance the Calendar component is one of them in my javaFX project. IMO Excel sheet can also follow that way as well. Alternatively I have seen Q&As about using Swing in JavaFX here on SO. Look at them for some hint.

Comment: Is it hard to extend an existing component in JavaFX 2? Are there any information about this?